# Probability distribution sampling from a trajectory

Tags: stochastic, probability

Disclaimer: this question was originally posted on Physics SE but with very limited replies and I am reproducing it here as a suggestion from one of the comments.

Consider a sequence of random variables $\{X_1, X_2,.., X_n\}$ corresponding to regular measurements of a single observable over time obtained from a laboratory or computer experiment.

Assume that the signal they form is sampling some underlying stationary distribution for the observable $X$ (like a Markov Chain would do for example), but that a priori the covariance $Cov(X_i, X_{i+k}) \neq 0$ unless $k > k_{\rm threshold} $.

My colleague states that if we want to characterise this distribution by building an empirical Cumulative Distribution Function (eCDF) we can do it using every single $X$-value in the sequence.

I am leaning towards thinking that the sampling must be made over a subset of the data spaced enough (larger than $k_{\rm threshold}$) so that each data point is mostly uncorrelated with the others.
This is to avoid the problem of autocorrelation or pseudo-replication [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreplication) . I am aware that it leads to problems in the estimation of the variance of the mean (when not corrected with autocorrelation data) [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_chain_central_limit_theorem&action=edit&section=3) and so I am not sure it is reliable for a more complete statistical picture of the distribution we want to sample like an eCDF.

I have 3 questions but which all revolve around the same issue presented above.

1. I have actually some difficulty finding any clear literature on this subject, even in the computer simulation texts I have consulted. From my own professional experience, people have various rules of thumbs and rarely compute averages or distributions from every step, but the reasoning put forward behind such practices can be as remote (to my query) as storage space. **Is anyone aware of mathematics/statitics/computational physics literature about this?**
2. **If my worry is unfounded, can someone explain to me why?**
3. **or if my worry is founded, is there a way to justify the pragmatic approach of my colleague of using all data at hand? By estimating the error perhaps?**

Answer (score 0):

Estimator of the PDF / CDF gets better with `N`, so if you're after the probability properties of the sampler, you should use them all.
See [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) for the analysis on the dependency on `N`.

See the below remarks about the validity of the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) for your case of [Weakly Dependent Random Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_dependent_random_variables).

If the original samples are going through some filtering, which creates correlation which depends on the properties of the filter (Mainly its bandwidth) then your trick might be a better estimator of the data before the filtration.
Though, I think for this case, better ways can be used (Estimate the filter).

In practice, sampled data is always filtered in some way or another.
For instance, the sampling rate can be a factor in the correlation level between samples.

In simulated data, then the filter, if exists, is defined by the simulation.

#### The Law of Large Numbers for Dependent Variables

For some cases where the [variables have weak dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_dependent_random_variables) (Like in the case above) the LLN is also valid. It is not too hard to prove such cases as can be seen in:

- [Weak Law of Large Numbers for Dependent Random Variables with Bounded Covariance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245327).
- [Strong Law of Large Numbers for Weakly Dependent Random Variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2409).
- [Russell Lyons - Strong Laws of Large Numbers for Weakly Correlated Random Variables](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-35/issue-3/Strong-laws-of-large-numbers-for-weakly-correlated-random-variables/10.1307/mmj/1029003816.full).

Comment: The law of large numbers only applies for independent random variables. It does not apply for correlated random variables (at least not as straighforwardly). I do not have a 'filter'. The sequence of $(X_1, .. ,X_n)$ stems from the trajectory of a system that is governed by some dynamical evolution operator.

Comment: @gatsu, No, the proofs on Wikipedia are classic. It has many variants including your case. I will add references so you will be able to see.

Comment: I am aware of these variants (that is why I added 'not straightforwardly') and am not particularly interested in them. They hardly serve any practical purpose, especially for estimating the error on a eCDF or ePDF apart from confirming the convergence in distribution of a sum of r.v. to some mean.

Comment: @gatsu, Those variants directly answers your question. If you want better accuracy for the convergence of the empirical CDF / PDF to the real CDF / PDF you better use all samples. If you have enough samples, you may take only those which are far apart.